# Laravel many-to-many sync Issue

Tags: database, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, relationship

I am currently working on a many-to-many, creating does not have any issue, but updating with pivot cause an issue **sometimes**.

here is some of my code

```
$request->value = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '3',
    'quantity' => '2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '21',
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '20',
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '19',
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
)  

$mcs->consumables()->sync($request->value);
```

After this code, when i check my database, somehow it duplicate one of the consumable_id.

i create a log on my update controller. updating 2 times

```
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: MCS ID : 2021042910  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Current Data...  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 21  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 1  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 20  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 1  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 19  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 1  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 3  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 1  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Request :   
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '21',
    'quantity' => '2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '20',
    'quantity' => '2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '19',
    'quantity' => '2',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '3',
    'quantity' => '4',
  ),
)  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Update Sync...  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 3  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 4  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 21  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 2  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 20  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 2  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 19  
[2021-04-29 10:45:49] local.INFO: Quantity : 2  

[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: MCS ID : 2021042910  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Current Data...  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 3  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 4  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 21  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 2  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 20  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 2  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 19  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 2  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Request :   
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '3',
    'quantity' => '2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '21',
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '20',
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'consumable_id' => '19',
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
)  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Update Sync...  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 19  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 1  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 19  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 1  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 21  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 1  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Consumbale ID : 20  
[2021-04-29 10:47:16] local.INFO: Quantity : 1
```

Did i missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i fixed my problem, the array index key was the culprit, i change my input field name.

```
name="input[consumable_id][quantity]"
```

The output

```
[2021-04-29 12:21:27] local.INFO: array (
  21 => 
  array (
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'quantity' => '2',
  ),
)
```

Hope someone find this helpful.